# Error: can't read server: no such variable when using ltk remotely

Tags: common-lisp, ltk

I am tinkering around with [ltk](http://www.peter-herth.de/ltk/) as it provides the option of running a remote GUI. However, when trying to use the remote GUI I run into issues I do not encounter when running ltk locally:

```
(in-package :ltk-user)


(defun add-current-investigation-frame (master)
  (let* ((frame (make-instance 'frame :master master :width 100 :height 100))
         (topic-label (make-instance 'label :text "Current Investigation" :master frame))
         (project-label (make-instance 'entry :text "N/A" :master frame))
         (action-button (make-instance 'button
                                       :master frame
                                       :text "new investigation")))
    (setf (command action-button) (lambda ()
                                    (format t "test~%")
                                    (let ((next-project (nth (random 3) '("A" "B" "N/A"))))
                                      (setf (text project-label) next-project))))
    (pack frame)
    (pack topic-label :side :top)
    (pack project-label :side :top)
    (pack action-button :side :top)))



(defun create-main-view ()
  (let ((wrapper-frame (make-instance 'frame :master nil)))
    (pack wrapper-frame)
    (add-current-investigation-frame wrapper-frame)))


(defun create-remote-view (&optional (port 8888))
  (Ltk:with-remote-ltk port ()
                       (create-main-view)))


(defun create-local-view ()
  (with-ltk ()
    (create-main-view)))
```

When running `(create-local-view)` everything works fine and the content of the entry widget changes randomly.

When running `(create-remote-view)` I get the error message `can't read server: no such variable`. **Why does this error occur and how can I fix this?**

I am using the `remote.tcl` deployed by quicklisp:

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

#    This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#    modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
#    License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
#    version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#    This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
#    Lesser General Public License for more details.

#    You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
#    License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
#    Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA


wm withdraw .
set host localhost
if {[llength $argv] == 2} {
    set host [lindex $argv 0]
    set port [lindex $argv 1]} else {
        set port [lindex $argv 0]}
#puts "connecting to $host $port"

set server [socket $host $port]
set wi [open "|wish" RDWR]
fconfigure $server -blocking 0
fconfigure $wi -blocking 0


fileevent $server readable {set txt [read $server];puts $wi "$txt";flush $wi}
fileevent $wi readable {
    if {[eof $wi]} {
        close $wi
        exit} else {        
            set txt [read $wi]; puts -nonewline $server $txt;flush $server}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a preliminary answer as I am not entirely sure that this fix does not break anything. I will update this answer in the future to report back on encountered issues. But for now this fixes the issue.

In `ltk.lisp` there is a function called `init-wish` which requires an additional line `(send-wish "set server stdout")`

```
(defun init-wish ()
 (send-lazy
  ;; print string readable, escaping all " and \
  ;; proc esc {s} {puts "\"[regsub {"} [regsub {\\} $s {\\\\}] {\"}]\""}
  ;(send-wish "proc esc {s} {puts \"\\\"[regsub -all {\"} [regsub -all {\\\\} $s {\\\\\\\\}] {\\\"}]\\\"\"} ")
  ;(send-wish "proc escape {s} {return [regsub -all {\"} [regsub -all {\\\\} $s {\\\\\\\\}] {\\\"}]} ")
   (send-wish "package require Tk")
;;; PUT MISSING LINE HERE
   (send-wish "set server stdout")
;;; PUT MISSING LINE HERE
  (flush-wish)

  #+:tk84
  (send-wish "catch {package require Ttk}")
  #-:tk84
  (send-wish "if {[catch {package require Ttk} err]} {tk_messageBox -icon error -type ok -message \"$err\"}")


  (send-wish "proc debug { msg } {
       global server
       puts $server \"(:debug \\\"[escape $msg]\\\")\"
       flush $server
    } ")
; more code ....
))
```

**Explanation:** The function seems to set up the wish interface and actions (confirmed by inserting prints in the `remote.tcl`). However, as one can see `server` is referenced in all procs yet it is never declared if we consider all those declarations to be in their own namespace. Consequently, the missing server has to be defined. As all the output is read by `fileevent $wi ...` and then passed on further, defining `server` as `stdout` seemed the most sensible.

**It seems to work, however I have no clue if this breaks other stuff**

Comment: As you may have forgotten: Are you aware of any resulting breakage? Is it possible that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68011245/remote-gui-with-ltk-doesnt-open-window is related? Thanks.

Comment: @Kotlopou no, worked fine for me without any further issues after I applied the fix

Answer (score 1):

So I spent some time reading and testing the code, and it appears that it works better with `remote-client.tcl` than `remote.tcl`. When working with `ltk-remote.lisp`, the Lisp side creates a server that may accept multiple clients, each client being a tcl/tk interpreter.

```
    lisp <=== socket stream ===> [ server socket ]
                                        ^
                                        |
                                 (wish interpreter)
```

The lisp side expects the interpreter to maintain a global variable named `server`. In the case of a local interpreter, this is done in `init-wish`, where there is `set server stdout`. In the case of a remote wish, it is expected that the wish interpreter sets this variable itself.

This is the case with `remote-client.tcl`, and the test applications works well (e.g. `ltk-remote::lrtest`), except that it adds a `.status` widget which is never removed. It should be possible to clean up a bit the `remote-client.tcl` script.

In the case of `remote.tcl`, the interpreter [opens](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl26.html) a pair of streams to another `wish` process:

```
set wi [open "|wish" RDWR]
```

It also connects to a server (variable `server`), and copies inputs from the server to the wish process. Unfortunately, the embedded wish process does not define a `server` variable:

```
    lisp <=== socket stream ===> [ server socket ]
                                        ^
                                        |
                                 (wish interpreter 1)
                                     "server" variable
                                        |
                                       "wi" variable
                                        ^
                                        | pipe connection
                                        v
                                 (wish interpreter 2) 
                                 no "server" variable
```

If however you set `server` to `stdout`, as explained in the other answer, this assignment is evaluated in the second wish interpreter. The output is sent back to the first wish interpreter, which copies the answer back to the lisp server.

Instead of going through another wish interpreter, I tested locally by using a modified `remote-client.tcl` that doesn't add any widget:

```
package require Tk

set host localhost
set port 19790
set server ""

if {[llength $argv] > 0} {
    set host [lindex $argv 0]
}

if {[llength $argv] > 1} {
    set port [lindex $argv 1]
}

if {[catch {global server; global host; global port; set server [socket $host $port]}]} {
    tk_messageBox -icon error -type ok -title "Connection failed!" -message "Cannot connect to server $host port $port."
    exit
}

fconfigure $server -blocking 0 -translation binary -encoding utf-8
fileevent $server readable [list sread $server]

set buffer ""

proc getcount {s} { 
    if {[regexp {^\s*(\d+) } $s match num]} {
        return $num
    }
}

proc getstring {s} { 
    if {[regexp {^\s*(\d+) } $s match]} {
        return [string range $s [string length $match] end]
    }
}

proc process_buffer {} {
    global buffer
    global server

    set count [getcount $buffer]
    set tmp_buf [getstring $buffer]

    while {($count > 0) && ([string length $tmp_buf] >= $count)} {
        set cmd [string range $tmp_buf 0 $count]
        set buffer [string range $tmp_buf [expr $count+1] end]

        if {[catch $cmd result]>0} {
            tk_messageBox -icon error -type ok -title "Error!" -message $result
            puts $server "(error: \"$result\")"
            flush $server
            close $server
            exit
        }
        set count [getcount $buffer]
        set tmp_buf [getstring $buffer]
    }
}

proc sread {server} {
    global buffer
    if {[eof $server]} {
        tk_messageBox -icon info -type ok -title "Connection closed" -message "The connection has been closed by the server."
        close $server
        exit
    } else {
        set txt [read $server];
        set buffer "$buffer$txt"
        process_buffer
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works better with `remote-client.tcl` than `remote.tcl`"? Running `remote-client.tcl` only prints events to the terminal (stdout?), it does not let you interact with the GUI.

Comment: I start a server using e.g. (ltk-remote::lrtest 5000), then in another terminal I execute "wish remote-client.tcl localhost 5000" and the callbacks seems to be working (clicking on "Quit" quits the application, etc). I'll have a look again tomorrow to be sure I did not miss something

Comment: Thanks, this works. The mistake was on my side - I left in the line from the other answer.